# `require_once` searching subdirectories of entire include_path?

Tags: php-5.3, windows-server-2012, iis-8, include-path, php-include

Is there a way to make `require_once` (and all of its cousins) not only search in the directories specified in `include_path`, but also all the subdirectories of those directories?

The reason I ask is I'm wanting to use this:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-sql-parser/

I've dropped the php-sql-parser main folder in my general c:\PHP\includes directory, which is included in the `include_path`. But because the actual .php file is in a sub-sub-subdirectory, it isn't found.

I can work around this by giving a full path to the main .php file, but it'd be nice just to not be that explicit.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to make `require_once` search subdirectories of `include_path` directories?
2. Is it for any reason a bad idea to do this?

Comment: I'd say this isn't generally recommended, although you could do some type of autoload hack. You can just include the file as `require_once 'subdir/file.php';`, and it will only look for the file under the specified subdirectory, but, anywhere in your include path.

Comment: I'm wondering about the usefulness of `include_path`, since libraries are contained in folders, and as such their main .php files will not appear directly in any folder in `include_path`. Am I thinking about this wrong?